# Book about clones using time travel to prevent cloning technology

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, clones

This would have been around the mid-2000s, with the book having been published fairly recently at the time I read it. It was in a school library, so probably leaning towards YA.

The plot, as I recall, was that a group of people had travelled back in time to the then-present, trying to avert the bad future they came from that featured an oppressed underclass of clones. I think one of them was called Anti Clone? They succeeded by encouraging someone in the present to pursue physics and develop fusion power, whereas in the original timeline he was the inventor of the cloning technology.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to have any recollection of the cover?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [*The Bradbury Report*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/6947944-the-bradbury-report) by Steven Polansky?

> It is 2071. A cloning program provides spare organs for the healthcare
> system. An unlikely candidate for adventure, Ray is a man in his
> sixties, who gets a call out of the blue from ex-girlfriend Anna. Now
> a political activist, she asks for his help to hide an escaped clone.
> The escapee is none other than his own clone.

This review mentions a time-travel theme

> The book The Bradbury Report, by Steven Polansky, is a science
> fiction/fantasy novel about a man who is one of only two people on the
> earth who knows the secret of time travel. By writing this book,
> Polansky is telling the readers a secret no one is supposed to know
> and which is censured by the government.